# prints output inspite of head->next being null

Tags: linked-list

```
void create(node *head)//function to create a linked list
{
int n;
printf("enter number");
printf("if end enter -999");
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n == -999)
{
    head=NULL;
}
else
{
    head->data=n;       
    head->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));        
    create(head->next);
}
return;
}

void print(node *head)//function to print linked list
{
if(head->next != NULL)
{
    printf("%d \n",head->data);
    print(head->next);
}
return;
}
```

here when first number is entered as 3 and next as -999,head->data should become 3 and `head->next` should be `NULL` and when print function is called it should not enter the if block as `head->next` is `NULL` but 3 is getting printed.

Why is 3 being printed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it all depends on, what you passed in print function(what is head in print function).

I suppose you wrote it like this, say in main function :-

head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

/////some more code

now you passed this head in print function which has value as 3 into it and head->next is NULL not head.
I am just assuming that this is the way u must have written your main function, if so, then i have answered your query.

Thanks